# HIVE "show partitions" command do not show correct partitions

Tags: hive, partition

i have a partition table with dynamic partitions, 
partition fields are nationality and birthdate,

when i use `select * from emp_new where nationality='China'`, i get the following three records,

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--+
| emp_new.name  | emp_new.sex  | emp_new.age  |   emp_new.job    | emp_new.nationality  | emp_new.birthdate  |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--+
| Tony          | M            | 34           | IT specialist    | China                | 198202             |
| Katrina       | F            | 33           | IT specialist    | China                | 198408             |
| Cathy         | F            | 30           | IT specialist    | China                | 198704             |
```

but when i run `show partitions emp_new partition(nationality='China')`, i get the following results:

```
+-------------------------------------+--+
|              partition              |
+-------------------------------------+--+
| nationality=China/birthdate=198408  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=198202  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=198704  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=197509  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=196704  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=197805  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=198201  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=197701  |
| nationality=China/birthdate=196708  |
+-------------------------------------+--+
```

Actually, I loaded the data into this table with static and dynamic partitions`(nationality='China', birthdate)` earlier, then truncated the table and reload with dynamic partitions `(nationality, birthdate)` later.

I don't understand why the old partitions are still there.

Comment: Replace the pictures with text (format it using ctrl+k) and add the table DDL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Truncate` deletes the table's data files.
It **does not** delete the partitions definitions from the metastore.
It **does not** delete the file system directories.

**Demo**

```
hive> create table mytable (i int) partitioned by (p int);
OK

hive> insert into mytable partition (p) values (1,10),(2,10),(3,20),(4,30),(5,30),(6,30);
OK
```

---

```
hive> select * from mytable;
OK
mytable.i   mytable.p
1   10
2   10
3   20
4   30
5   30
6   30


hive> show partitions mytable;
OK
partition
p=10
p=20
p=30

hive> !tree ../local_db/mytable;
../local_db/mytable
├── p=10
│   └── 000000_0
├── p=20
│   └── 000000_0
└── p=30
    └── 000000_0

3 directories, 3 files
```

---

```
hive> truncate table mytable;
OK
```

---

```
hive> select * from mytable;
OK
mytable.i   mytable.p

hive> show partitions mytable;
OK
partition
p=10
p=20
p=30

hive> !tree ../local_db/mytable;
../local_db/mytable
├── p=10
├── p=20
└── p=30

3 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: thanks, then how to truncate the table and at the same time 
delete the partitions definitions from the metastore and delete the file system directories ?

Comment: First thing first. Have you seen my comment to your post?

Comment: @tonyibm, table DDL?

Comment: create table emp_new(name string, sex string,age int, job string) partitioned by (nationality, birthdate) row format delimited fields terminated by '|' collection items terminated by ','

Comment: @tonyibm - No, this is not a working code. Also add it to your original post and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

i know the reason, 
i need to drop the partition after truncate the table, 
thanks